# Apple Watch and openParentApplication in background

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I am implementing a apple watch. In my extension of the Watchkit i use the method to communicate to the "main app".

```
    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:applicationData reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {}];
```

According to apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH3-SW1), the app can handle the request in background.

```
When you call the openParentApplication:reply: method, iOS launches or 
wakes up the parent app in the background and calls the
application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:method of its app delegate.
```

However my app always became active, even if i have no code inside the method, **handleWatchKitExtensionRequest**

Any tips if it´s possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to official response from Apple dev on Apple Developer Forum this is bug in Beta 2 of WatchKit Framework.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1082689#1082689

> And just to be clear about one thing, the iPhone app is lauched in the
>   background.  In the simulator currently the app is being launched in
>   the foreground.  This will not be the experience on device.  The
>   documentation specifically says, "Calling the method causes iOS to
>   launch the app in the background ...".

(Post number 6)

BTW, yesterday Beta 3 was released, maybe it's already fixed.

What is more if iPhone will be locked your iOS app also will be launched in background.

Comment: Release Notes (Beta 3) - The WKInterfaceController method openParentApplication:reply: now launches the containing app in the background when the iPhone (or iOS Simulator) is unlocked or locked.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is not active, openParentApplication cannot activate it. It can only perform tasks in the background. For this to work, it is important that you   start a background task in `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:). This ensures that the main app on the iPhone is not suspended before it can send its reply.

Code in the app delegate of the main app on iPhone:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void ( ^)( NSDictionary * ))reply 
{
   __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier watchKitHandler;
   watchKitHandler = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
          beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"backgroundTask"
                    expirationHandler:^{
              watchKitHandler = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
          }];

   if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] isEqualToString:@"getData"]) {
      // get data
      // ...
      reply( data );
   }

   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)NSEC_PER_SEC * 1), dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:watchKitHandler];
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a background mode missing in the "capabilities" section for the main app and it will be added in the future.

I tried turning on all of the currently supported background modes, and none of them worked (i.e. the main application was always launching).

My tip - patience till the next beta.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem bolting WatchKit onto an existing app.  I had `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` (aka Application does not run in background) set to `YES` in the info.plist. Change it to `NO` and the error goes away.